# Is a connected set union limit point a connected set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Good night, I'm trying this exercise:

> Let $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ connected and let $x$ be an accumulation point of $C$. Prove that $C\cup\{x\}$ is connected.

I understand the exercise, geometrically at least, it makes a lot of sense but no luck trying to prove it, by previous examples, I get that, the idea of working with contentedness is by contradiction using the disjoint sets that their union are the disconnected set, but I can't get to use the definition of accumulation point in my proof, any hints or ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that $C\cup\{x\}$ is not connected and take $A\cup B$ a separation of $C\cup\{x\}$. As $C$ is connected then $C$ is contained in some part of the separation, say $A$. As $B$ is open and $x$ an accumulation point, what can you conclude?

Comment: So, i can say, suppose that $x\in B$, we can find a $\epsilon$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subset B$ but, since $x$ is an accumulation point of $c$, that cannot happen, so we must have that $x\in A$, but from there? can we say that $B=\varnothing$? and if we can, is there a problem that $B=\varnothing$? or if we have that $A=C\cup\{x\}$ is enough to say that $C\cup\{x\}$ is connected?

Comment: Once $C\cup\{x\}\subseteq A$ you already won! Recall that, by definition, a separation of $X$ is a pair of disjoint, clopens and $\textbf{non empty}$ sets $A$ and $B$ such that $X=A\cup B$.

Comment: If $C\subset A$ then $x\in B$ because $B\cap (C\cup \{x\})\ne \emptyset$ and $B\cap C= B\cap (C\cap A)\subset $ $(B\cap (C\cup \{x\}))\cap$ $ (A\cap (C\cup \{x\}))$ $=\emptyset.$. But $B$ is a nbhd of $x$ so $B\cap C \ne \emptyset$ because $x$ is an accumulation point of $C$. This implies there exists $y\in B\cap C=B\cap C \cap A,$ a contradiction.

Comment: @DanielCalderón this argument fails if the topological space does not have the hausdorff property right? since then C Union {x} could potentially be two disjoint open sets?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A=C\cup\{x\}$ is disconnected, then there exist open subsets $U$ and $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

1. $A \subset U \cup V$
2. $A\cap U\neq\emptyset$ and $A\cap V\neq\emptyset$
3. $A\cap U\cap V=\emptyset$

From these three facts above prove that $U\cup V$ is a disconnection of $C$, which contradicts the connectedness of $C$.

Comment: I think that point 3, should be $A\cap U\cap V=\emptyset.$

Comment: Indeed, it is. But it got edited. Now's correct, thanks.